# C# A variable that cannot be changed outside of function

Tags: c#

Is it possible to declare a variable inside a called function, and no external source can change this variable? For example:

```
private void SetVariable(){
    privatetypevariable variable = "hello";
}

variable = "world"; //<-- doesnt work because it cannot access the variable 'variable' inside SetVariable()
```

How do I access the variable outside of the scope of the above method?

Comment: No, it is not possible. Variable is visible only in the same and nested scopes.

Comment: local variable cannot not be accessed  outside method

Comment: You need to properly grasp concepts like scope and encapsulation

Comment: VB.Net and other languages support static variables inside methods, but C# doesn't https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/csharpfaq/2004/05/11/why-doesnt-c-support-static-method-variables/

Comment: please see this [page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691132(v=vs.71).aspx)

Comment: Just declare the variable inside the function - then it cannot be accessed outside; `var scopedLocally = "hello";`

Comment: Isn't your example a demonstration of what you're asking?

Comment: @apokryfos Not really, because I dont know how to actually implement it lol

Comment: @LachlanMather For a good starting point, read up on `global` and `local` scope here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33108958/differences-between-local-and-global-variables. `Global` = accessible to all methods (`public void someMethod()`) in your class, `local` = only usable between the braces (`{ }`) of the method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of declaring the variable in the method define it as a class field. Then you can change it from anywhere inside the class. Fields are generally marked as private so it cannot be changed outside the class. If you want to expose it outside the class use a property instead with a public type.

```
private privatetype fielda;
void methodA(){
    fielda = "hello";
}

void someOtherMethod()
{
    fielda = fielda + " world"; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It wouldn't be possible due to the fact that a variable only lives inside its given scope, as soon as you exit the scope, the variable is lost.
To add to that, you can't add visibility modifiers to your variables declared in a method

The below code won't work since s only lives in the scope of methodA() and is lost as soon as you exit the scope.

```
private void methodA(){
    String s = "hello";
}

private void methodB(){
    s = s + " world"; //even tho methodA created an s variable, it doesn't exist in the eyes of methodB
}
```

You could do something as follows:

```
class someClass{
    private String s;

    public someClass(){
        s = "hello world";
    }

    public String getVariable(){ //you can read this variable, but you can't set it outside of this class.
        return s; 
    }
```

}

Answer (score 0):

If you specify a variable inside a function, it is scoped to only that function in C#.

Example 1:

```
    private void foo(string bar)
    {
       string snark = "123";
    }

    private void derk()
    {
       snark = "456";
    }
```

Example 1 would cause a compile error. If you mean inside a class, declare the property as `readonly` and it cannot be changed outside of it's initial constructor.

Example 2:

```
    public class Lassy
    {
       private readonly string _collarColour;

       public Lassy(string collarColour)
       {
          _collarColour = collarColour;
       }

       private void SetCollarColour(string newColour)
       {
          _collarColour = newColour;
       }
    }
```

Example 2 will also cause a compile error because you cannot assign to a `readonly` attribute in a class outside of it's initial constructor.

To achieve what you want, use `readonly`.